# jQuery Calendars Datepicker generates error: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar, persian

I want to use jQuery Calendars Datepicker with a textbox. The documentation and samples : [jQuery Calendars Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html)

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="TarikhTavalod" value="" id="TarikhTavalod" placeholder="تاریخ تولد" class="form-control date-picker">
```

Javascript:

```
$('.date-picker').calendarsPicker();
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I imported these files:

```
jquery.calendars.js
jquery.calendars.plus.js
jquery.calendars.picker-fa.js
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: can you post your code in one piece, like your whole html (related sections of course)

Comment: are there multiple versions of jQuery...

Comment: in your browser console check for any previous errors.. also check whether the path to the calendar plugin js files are correct

Comment: The whole html is so big! I have just JQuery 2.1.3. There is no other errors and the path is correct?